# How to implement login module Android

Tags: android, authentication, autologin

How i can to implement in my Android application a login module ?

What that i want to do is simple, after the startup of the application, user must be login by insertion of personal data like email or password.

After the login and after that the data are controlled by a query to the database, user can access at the rest of the application, maintaining the login session until the user 
log off.

I wish it were possible to log in automatically...

I would know how cookies / session work in Android.
p.s. the login process must be executed in an activity not in the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use a service like [Parse](http://www.parse.com) for this since it will provide a lot of the code for you.

[This post](http://blog.parse.com/2014/06/25/login-love-for-your-android-app/) on their blog describe how to add login functionality to your app.